# Passing a value from my Gruntfile to an external Grunt task

Tags: javascript, grunt.js

In my Gruntfile, I use the grunt-contrib-watch task to watch a directory for file changes:

```
watch: {
    releases: {
        files: ['source/md/releases/*.md'],
        tasks: ['process:auto']
    }
}
```

Also, in the Gruntfile, I have a "watch" event handler. Inside this handler, I temporarily store the file path of the file that was modified, so that my task can read this information and only process that file:

```
grunt.event.on('watch', function (action, filepath, target) {
    if (target === 'releases') {
        grunt.file.write('filepath.txt', filepath);
    }
});
```

Then, inside my Grunt task (which is located in "tasks/process.js"), I read that file:

```
if (this.target === 'auto') {
    path = grunt.file.read('filepath.txt');

    // process file at given path

    grunt.file.delete('filepath.txt'); // delete this temporary file
}
```

---

Having to share the file path information via a file certainly doesn't seem optimal, but I haven't found a better solution yet. Note that writing the file path information directly into the configuration of my task from within the "watch" handler:

```
grunt.config('process.auto.filepath', filepath);
```

only works with the `spawn:false` setting in the "watch" configuration. I cannot set this option because then there is a 10 second delay between "watch" events (i.e. file modifications are ignored in that period).

Comment: Can you not simply `require` your `tasks\process.js` and do a straight forward function call? See this: http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.task#loading-externally-defined-tasks

Comment: @konijn The link you provided describes a `.loadTasks()` function which I already use to load my externally defined task into Grunt. This enables referencing the task by name; see `'process:auto'` in my first code block above. *** If I required my code manually, where would I call it from? The only place I can think of is from within the "watch" event handler. However, the docs recommend against this practice. Read here: https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch#using-the-watch-event

Answer (score 1):

Since file is an object, and it has a constructor, that can be use to store the file path:

```
grunt.event.on('watch', function (action, filepath, target) {
    if (target === 'releases') {
        grunt.file.constructor.filepath = filepath;
    }
});
```

**References**

- [Why Composition is Harder with Classes – JavaScript Scene – Medium](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/why-composition-is-harder-with-classes-c3e627dcd0aa)
- [grunt/file.js at master · gruntjs/grunt](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt/blob/master/lib/grunt/file.js)